# API for getting episode air date of series

Tags: api, series, movies

Do you guys know any API that provides access to episode air time? I want to make a little app that will remind me of episodes coming out from my favorite shows. (Something like a rss feed of what episodes came out since my last check. 
(Feel free to link me to an existing app if existing).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

http://thetvdb.com/ does that. Alot of larger projects, such as [XBMC](http://xbmc.org/) use it as their main API for such things.

FYI the API can be found [here](https://api.thetvdb.com/swagger)

Comment: thanks! this is awesome. using it for my app csomakk.github.io/IWatchSeriez source available on github